# Which is the action or code “specified”?

Tags: javascript

```
let specialty = ‘’;

function isVegetarian() {
};

function isLowSodium() {
};

export { specialty, isVegetarian };

export { specialty, isVegetarian };
```

The editor explained as this :

> slight_smile: exports objects by their variable names. Notice the
>   keyword export is the prefix. specialty and isVegetarian are exported,
>   while isLowSodium is not exported, since it is not specified.

my question is why the `isLowSodium` is not specified? They look as the same.
So we can `export{specialty .isLowSodium}`?
I did not see any action and difference about the "specified".

Comment: Why would it get exported unless you explicitly ask for it to be exported?

Comment: ok ,it just is a exercise ,the link :https://www.codecademy.com/courses/intermediate-javascript-modules/lessons/modules/exercises/named-exports?action=lesson_resume&course_redirect=introduction-to-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to have access to `isLowSodium()` you'd need to pass it along the exported properties.

As it is now, when you attempt to use the file by importing its members you'd only have access to `specialty` and `isVegetarian` as they were the only ones exported.

Comment: this means if i add as export { specialty, isLowSodium }; it can work also ,this is ok ?

Comment: @vincentyang Why not try it and find out?

Comment: Yes, kinda like `export { specialty, isLowSodium, isVegetarian }`. In this all properties are exported or `export { specialty, isLowSodium }`, in this case `isVegetarian` is not exported.